# JavaFx, printing PDF (From PDFBOx)

Tags: pdf, javafx, printing, pdfbox

I have a JavaFX application that generates a PDF with Apache PDFBox. And I would like to print that PDF.

However, I was not able to find a good solution.

I have tried with the `java.awt.print.PrinterJob` but it hangs when calling the `PrinterJob#printDialog(..)` method. The mouse cursor becomes "wait" and I cannot use the application anymore.

I have tried with `javafx.print.PrinterJob`. It can show the print dialog but I do not find a way to print something else than a node.

At this time, I print with the `java.awt.Desktop` API. It print my PDF but skip the print dialog.

So, **my question is:** How can I display the print dialog and print a PDF (ideally an `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument`) from JavaFX?

My project uses Java 17 (Open Jdk) and JavaFX 16. I have the issue on MacOS and never tried on other OS.

Instead of printing the `PDDocument` I can also write it to he disk and print the `File` or convert it to any kind of stream.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you tried using AWT's print API, did you execute that code on the EDT (instead of the JavaFX Application Thread)?

Comment: No, I did not. Now I have changed that and everything is fine (at least the dialog shows as expected).

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as [enlighted by @Saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578143/javafx-printing-pdf-from-pdfbox?noredirect=1#comment126506869_71578143), was because I was not trying to open the AWT print dialog from the EDT.

The solution is to wrap that code into a `Runnable` submitted to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    var job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setJobName(report.getTitle());
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(report.getDocument()));
    if (job.printDialog()) {
        job.print();
    }
});
```